# Unable to clear range picker after date is selected in ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

Unable to clear date range picker from ant design after user selects date.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const DataTable = props => {
  const [dateRange, changeDateRange] = useState(null);

  const onDateRangeChange = dateRange => {
    if (dateRange) {
      changeDateRange(returnMomentDateRange(dateRange[0], dateRange[1]));
    }
  };

  const returnMomentDateRange = (start, finish) => {
    return [moment(start, "YYYY-MM-DD"), moment(finish, "YYYY-MM-DD")];
  };

  return (
    <RangePicker
      allowClear={true}
      size="small"
      picker="date"
      value={dateRange !== "" ? dateRange : ""}
      onChange={onDateRangeChange}
    />
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

It seems that once I add a value prop, I can no longer clear using the 'x'.

This is a codesandbox I setup.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-rgb-xidbz?file=/src/App.js:0-754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method onDateRangeChange use following code,

```
if (dateRange) {
   changeDateRange(returnMomentDateRange(dateRange[0], dateRange[1]));
} else {
   changeDateRange([]);
}
```

Comment: very close. `null` does not work, but an empty array does; if you change your answer to that, i will accept it. thank you for your help.

Comment: @schoenbl null works for me and should work for you, because initial value of `dateRange` is also but. But `[ ]` empty array also works, so i changed it. You can accept answer.

Comment: you're right; it wasn't working for a different reason; i have a slightly different version of it in my local environment. you should probably change it back. sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your help.